# How to add creases to flow wrapped package

Tags: modeling, transforms, sculpting

I have the following model:

[image]

I want to add some creases to the mesh to make it look like metallic flow wrapped package like the following

[image]

What is the best way to achieve that look? I've tried cloth simulation but it creates too many creases. I want some creases on some areas.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried a bit of sculpt?

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for the reply. Yes but it doesn't look natural. I'm not sure If I'm doing it right. Which brush should I try ?

Comment: the default one (Draw)? and Ctrl to invert its effect. Also the Crease one

Comment: You can also try turning up the cloth settings so it’s closer to metal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try in *Sculpt* mode with the *Cloth* brush (not easy to handle imho).

You could also use the *Cloth > Pressure* feature, first create a vertex group that you'll pin:

[image]

Then give your object a *CLoth* simulation with *Pressure* (more than 0), play the animation, it's going to inflate except where you've pinned:

[image]

At the end you can use the *Cloth Filter* brush > *Pinch* option to get that:

[image]

You could also project a aluminium-like image texture on your pack:

[image]

Then subdivide your object and give it a bit of volume with the sculpt *Draw* brush for example (also *Draw Sharp* and *Crease*), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to invert the effect, <kbd>Shift</kbd> to smooth:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I've tried it today but it didn't work. Here is my result: https://i.imgur.com/jU5SFhV.png. What settings did you used on the example above?

Comment: maybe increase the pressure? If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. It breaks after increasing slightly the pressure. https://pasteall.org/blend/99c5facc9b1d4e1fb338613f071e1100

Comment: try this: Add a Subdivision Surface above the Cloh modifier (Level 2), Put the Field Weights > Gravity at 0, Increase the Pressure value, choose the group you’ve created under Shape > Pin Group, choose another setup like for example Cotton (top dropdown menu of the Cloth panel). Also maybe apply the scale.